# WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody while running sample google calendar

Tags: java, eclipse, google-calendar-api

I am running google calendar sample then i am getting below error.
When running the Java quickstart sample at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java in eclipse, I'm receiving the error code:

```
 Nov 23, 2015 12:23:29 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\Shree\.credentials\calendar-java-quickstart
Nov 23, 2015 12:23:29 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\Shree\.credentials\calendar-java-quickstart
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at main.java.CalendarQuickstart.authorize(CalendarQuickstart.java:69)
at main.java.CalendarQuickstart.getCalendarService(CalendarQuickstart.java:92)
at main.java.CalendarQuickstart.main(CalendarQuickstart.java:104)
```

Any help

Comment: How about sharing the code that produces this error?

Comment: Thanks for your response for the code i provided the link

Comment: In this link there is step 3 that is code only The Link  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java

Comment: The sample doesn't include anything about updating permissions.   Have you changed something?

Comment: I didn't change anything i just follow the steps and run the application in eclipse and i didn't use gradle instead i added jars

Comment: it only does a calendars list.  it doesn't do change permissions.  Error seams strange.   You wont be able to update anything using the scope CALENDAR_READONLY

Comment: yes exactly but what is solutions i just want to check output